# django migrations issues with postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-migrations

I'm working on a Django project which dockerized and using Postgres for the database, but we are facing migrations issues, every time someone made changes in the model so if the other dev took a pull from git and try to migrate the migrations using `python manage.py migrate` because we already have the migrations file so sometimes the error is `table already exists` or `table doesn't exists` so every time I need to apply migrations using `--fake` but I guess that's not a good approach to migrate every time using `--fake` flag.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER=POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  app:
    container_name: app
    build: 
      context: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./core:/app
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./core/ /app/
COPY ./scripts /scripts

# installing nano and cron service
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN apt-get install nano

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# install dependencies and manage assets
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media

# files for cron logs
RUN mkdir /cron
RUN touch /cron/django_cron.log

# start cron service
RUN service cron start
RUN service cron restart

RUN chmod +x /scripts/run.sh

CMD ["/scripts/run.sh"]
```

`run.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

ls -la /vol/
ls -la /vol/web

whoami

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate
service cron start 
service cron restart
python manage.py crontab add 
printenv > env.txt
cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root >> env.txt
cat env.txt > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root 

uwsgi --socket :9000 --workers 4 --master --enable-threads --module alectify.wsgi
```

Comment: I think your problem has very little to do with docker and is probably caused by how you are using git. Migrations are always a delicate matter working together on the same codebase. Suggestions: 1) Always try to setup your models at the beginning and try not to change them unless really necessary 2) Organize in a way that people do not does make changes to models at the same time, so if one changes a model the other must wait the push, get the changes, rebase his codebase and make his changes the changes to the model and remember to tell each other that you are making changes to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Django offers the ability to create updated migrations when the models change see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#workflow for more information, but you can generate then apply updated migrations using:

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```